# Warning: enumeration value ‘BUILT_IN_CILK_SYNC’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I'm trying to install gcc on cygwyn using [this tutorial](http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/). After this step `$ make -j4` I'm facing lots of warnings:

```
           ^
../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/asan.c:2012:11: warning: enumeration value ‘BUILT_IN_ACOS’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/asan.c:2012:11: warning: enumeration value ‘BUILT_IN_ACOSF’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/asan.c:2012:11: warning: enumeration value ‘BUILT_IN_ACOSH’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/asan.c:2012:11: warning: enumeration value ‘BUILT_IN_ACOSHF’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
../../gcc-4.9.2/gcc/asan.c:2012:11: warning: enumeration value ‘BUILT_IN_ACOSHL’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
```

Will they cause any problem? What are these?

Comment: the current gcc on cygwin is 5.4.0. You are wasting time to recompile 4.9.2 old version with 5.4.0 as compiler. The tutorial is of course obsolete

Comment: @matzeri Should I uninstall this version or I can just install the new version?

Comment: what is the output of `gcc --version` ?

Comment: @matzeri gcc (GCC) 5.4.0

Comment: so you have already it. No actions needed.

Answer (score 0):

the current gcc on cygwin is 5.4.0. You are wasting time to recompile 4.9.2 old version with 5.4.0 as compiler. The tutorial is of course obsolete – matzeri